# Reg: Change in Query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have a requirement in oracle forms to write a PLSQL block that would read from the database through a cursor that contains comma separated record. I have completed the logic but wanted to check if this logic which I have developed can be improved in any way.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR vest_hist (p_ind_id NUMBER,
                  p_plan_id NUMBER)
IS  
SELECT narrative
  FROM dummy_ev_tbld
 WHERE subject_id = p_ind_id
   AND sub_subject_id = p_plan_id
   AND evty_code = 'VEDC'
 ORDER BY dpdate_time;
    
 v_narrative dummy_ev_tbld.narrative%TYPE;
 v_hire_date VARCHAR2(11);
 v_ev_id VARCHAR2(10);
 v_step_seqnbr VARCHAR2(3);
 v_credited_hours VARCHAR2(10);
 BEGIN
 OPEN vest_hist(123,
                123);
 LOOP -- looping for the child ga_id's
 FETCH vest_hist INTO v_narrative;
 EXIT WHEN vest_hist%notfound;   
 v_hire_date := NVL(SUBSTR(v_narrative,INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,3)+1,INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,4)-INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,3)-1),'N/A');
 v_ev_id := NVL(SUBSTR(v_narrative,INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,4)+1,INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,5)-INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,4)-1),'N/A');
 v_step_seqnbr := NVL(SUBSTR(v_narrative,INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,5)+1,INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,6)-INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,5)-1),'N/A');
 v_credited_hours := NVL(SUBSTR(v_narrative,INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,9)+1,INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,10)-INSTR(v_narrative,',',1,9)-1),'N/A');`your text`
         /*DO SOMETHING with these variables......*/
 END LOOP;
 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('E-1526-0004-0038-'||SQLCODE||':Contact Systems');
 RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;    
 END;
```

So I am using the substr and instr to split the narrative data and then storing them in the respective variable. So is there any way I can do it in one query or logic?

**The v_narrative data: 14-JUL-2019,92149,1,10**

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you could pay attention to.

The first one is that code you posted won't work because of `NVL` function calls. One of local variables is `DATE`, the rest of them are `NUMBER`s and you can't put `N/A` into any of them because that's a string.

Furthermore, are you *sure* that - for sample `narrative` value (`14-JUL-2019,92149,1,10`) your *substrings* return correct values? You're searching for e.g. 9th or 10th appearance of a comma character in it. There aren't that many commas there.

As of exception handler: although it won't fail, it won't do anything because Oracle Forms is incapable of displaying output of `dbms_output.put_line`. Use `message` built-in (call it twice so that is displayed in a pop-up window on the screen, or switch to alert.

How to simplify that code? Get rid of explicitly declared cursor, cursor variable, local variables, opening the cursor (and closing it - which is what you failed to do), worrying about exiting the loop and switch to a cursor `for` loop.

Here's a suggestion which shows alternative way of doing it.

```
 begin
   for cur_r in 
     (select to_date(substr(narrative, 1, 11), 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english') hire_date,
       substr(narrative, instr(narrative, ',', 1, 1) + 1,
                   instr(narrative, ',', 1, 2) - instr(narrative, ',', 1, 1) - 1
             ) ev_id,
       substr(narrative, instr(narrative, ',', 1, 2) + 1,
                   instr(narrative, ',', 1, 3) - instr(narrative, ',', 1, 2) - 1
             ) step_seqnbr,
       substr(narrative, instr(narrative, ',', 1, 3) + 1) credited_hours             
      from dummy_ev_tbld
   ) loop
     null;
     -- do something with values returned by cursor. Reference them as e.g.
     -- if cur_r.hire_date is null then ...
  end loop;
exception
  when others then
    message('E-1526-0004-0038-'||SQLCODE||':Contact Systems');
    raise form_trigger_failure;
end;
/
```

Comment: Sorry i have changed the post with the right variable. Since i am using this in oracle forms and storing it in the datablock, all the variables are Varchar variables.

Comment: You should have done that *before* posting the question. We know only what you tell us, so - if that's not correct - you'll get answer which corresponds to false information you provided. Nonetheless, that doesn't change much what I've already said.